# Python: an elegant way to extract floats from list?

Tags: python, list, extract

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

I have a "double" list of the form:

```
rlist = [([-0.5753647], [1.3716470]), ([-0.57536478], [0.75418190]), ([-1.37632438], [0.57068748])]
```

from which I want to extract individual floating point numbers, formatted.

At the moment I'm using:

```
first_number = round(float(str(rlist[0][0]).strip('[]')),4)
```

for example, to get the first number. This is rather ugly.  Is there a more succinct way to do it (in Python)?

DN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from itertools import chain
[round(x, 4) for x in chain(*chain(*rlist))]
```

`itertools.chain` can be used to flatten nested iterables. After that you can use list comprehension and `round` to obtain list of numbers with required precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opting for `itertools.chain()`, if level of nesting is more `please see the comments below this answer` by @zero323

And round() has also some restrictions too,

```
f = -0.5753647

print f

-0.57536469999999995

print round(f, 4)

-0.57540000000000002
```

So,

```
rlist = [([-0.5753647], [1.3716470]),
     ([-0.57536478], [0.75418190]),
     ([-1.37632438], [0.57068748])]

def flatten(container):

    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, list) or isinstance(i, tuple):
            for j in flatten(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i

print ["{0:.4f}".format(ele) for ele in list(flatten(rlist))]
```

Comment: 1. Check this `from random import random; list(chain(*chain(*chain(*[[[[random()] for x in range(2)] for y in range(3)] for z in range(4)]))))` You can try with deeper nesting and you'll see it works fine. 2. Casting to string doesn’t solve the problem and gives output different than required by @dcnicholls. You could use `decimal.Decimal` if fp representations is really a problem 3. Using `isinstance` is usually discouraged. `hasattr(i, "__iter__")` would be probably a better solution.

Comment: The suggestion you mentioned in the comment is complex and hard to understand, **chain()** method is being called one inside another, what if you are not aware of the nesting level ?

Comment: IMHO there is nothing complex in nesting functions but it is probably matter of taste. About not being aware of the nesting. In the context of this question it is not really important because format is fixed. But generally speaking recursion can be dangerous in this case. Not mention that is much slower than `chain`. Try running this: `from random import randint; foo = [[[[randint(1,10)] for x in range(1)] for y in range(1000)] for z in range(1000)]; %timeit list(chain(*chain(*chain(*foo)))); %timeit list(flatten(foo))` and you'll see.

Comment: I have to agree that in some cases recursive solution could be better and I am not here to argue. All I wanted to point out is that your claim about `chain` and nesting is wrong, output is different than expected and `isinstance` is not the best solution.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I was trying to present in a simple and more understandable manner to the one who really new to python